# Ionic toolbar too wide for some displays

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework

I have the following toolbar rendering in my ionic app:

[image]

You may be able to tell that the two furthest left and right icons don't appear to have the same padding either side, it's obviously too wide for the screen. this becomes even more evident when I emulate a smaller width mobile device:

[image]

I would've expected the ionic framework to deal with this since it's supposed to aid app development.

How can I ensure the toolbar fully fits in all mobiles devices regardless of width?

### Code:

```
<ion-header :translucent="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment value="all">
      <ion-segment-button value="camera"><ion-icon :icon="cameraOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="albums"><ion-icon :icon="albumsOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="people"><ion-icon :icon="peopleOutline" color="inactiveitem"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="compass"><ion-icon :icon="compassOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="calendar"><ion-icon :icon="calendarOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="settings"><ion-icon :icon="settingsOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon></ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: use: `scrollable`  attribute to make them scroll and they will get adjusted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @NajamUsSaqib - can you elaborate a little please? Which element should I add this to?

Comment: your main `<ion-segment >` tag.

Comment: Excellent! Worked first time, thank you very much! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work on all screen use `scrollable` attribute.

```
<ion-segment value="all" scrollable >
  <ion-segment-button value="camera">
     <ion-icon :icon="cameraOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>

  <ion-segment-button value="all">
     <ion-icon :icon="cameraOutline" color="primary"></ion-icon>
  </ion-segment-button>
  
</ion-segment>
```